# What do "reminders", "other_multiline", "appcenter_request" mean in the Internal Referral Sources table?

Tags: facebook-insights, referrals

I'm analysing the Internal Referral Sources table for my app in the Facebook insights and I don't know what the following items are:

1. reminders
2. other_multiline
3. appcenter_request

Answer (score 1):

1. reminders = At the top of the right hand column on the News Feed, we will surface reminders for commonly used applications. These appear near birthday reminders, pokes, and other notifications. Clicks from here will have the reminders fb_source parameter appended.
2. other_multiline =
   Found when a user is brought to your app through an open graph multi-line story. Currently this fb_source param can be found in stories on timeline, ticker and newsfeed.
3. appcenter_request = When a user clicks on a request from within App Center, we set the fb_source value to appcenter_request.

Source https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fb_source